# Make named import of Sass file available as a string

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, webpack-4

I'm building a web component in React and need to pass my compiled component styles, which are written in Sass, into the the component's `<style>` tag as a string.

Component code:
`<MyWebComponent>` is already successfully set up to make the component's shadow using [ReactShadow](https://github.com/Wildhoney/ReactShadow)

It's currently working if I use a compiled CSS file using this `import` statement:

```js
import componentCSS from '!!css-loader!./my-component/index.css';
```

I need:

- to use an SCSS file in that `import`
- to do away with the inline `!!css-loader!` loader config syntax in the component code

```js
import componentCSS from './my-component/index.scss';

...

render() {
  return (
    <MyWebComponent shadowStyles={[componentCSS]}> // componentCSS needs to be a string
      <h1>Hello Web Component</h1>
    </MyWebComponent>
  );   
}
```

If I `console.log(componentCSS)`, I get an empty object `{}`.

the style bits of Webpack config:

```js
...
{
      test: /\.scss$/,
      include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, './web-components'),
      ],
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: { importLoaders: 1 }
        },
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: { sourceMap: true }
        },
        {
          loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
          options: { sourceMap: true }
        },
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: { sourceMap: true, outputStyle: 'compressed' }
        },
        {
          loader: '@epegzz/sass-vars-loader',
          options: {
            syntax: 'scss',
            files: [path.resolve(__dirname, './scss/index.scss')]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, './web-components'),
      use: [
        'raw-loader'
      ]
    },
...
```

I've explored making a custom loader to no success, like trying to replace the import string in the component code with the working inline loader syntax:

```js
// my-loader.js / Custom webpack loader
module.exports = function(content) {
  content = content.replace(
    "import componentCSS from './my-component/index.scss'", 
    `import componentCSS from '@epegzz/sass-vars-loader?syntax=scss&files[]=${path.resolve(__dirname, './scss/index.scss')}!sass-loader!css-loader!./my-component/index.scss'`
  )
  return content;
};
```

Before I go too far down the custom loader rabbit hole, is there a config option or syntax change that is possible to make it work?